# Help with a bash script to proceed if bundle id is found

Tags: terminal, bash

Looking for some help writing a bash script that checks if a particular bundle id is installed and proceeds to install the package if not found.

Found that we can use "mdfind kMDItemCFBundleIdentifier = "com.hnc.Discord" (for example) returns the location for the particular bundleid if the app is not found nothing comes back.  Maybe I can use this with an if statement somehow?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mdfind` does not produce an unsuccessful exit code but you could pipe the results to `grep` which does. The code would look something like this:

```
mdfind "kMDItemCFBundleIdentifier = com.apple.Terminal" | grep -q Terminal || installer ....
```

`||` is logical or.

It could also be written

```
if mdfind "kMDItemCFBundleIdentifier = com.apple.Terminal" | grep -q Terminal
then
  :
else
  installer ...
fi
```

Comment: That would work!  Any way we can make the grep universal instead of a specific term? The bundle id will end up being a variable.

Comment: @WebsterMaster What do you mean with universal? You can use a shell variable instead of `com.apple.Terminal`, also `[[ $(mdfind "kMDItemCFBundleIdentifier = $BUNDLEID" | wc -l) -eq 0 ]]` will avoid the `grep` part. Or use `... -gt 0` and run the installer in the `then` part.